# Can't add new database connection in Pentaho Spoon

Tags: java, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, data-integration

I have a problem with adding new database connection in Pentaho Spoon 8.3
After adding "Table output" click on "New" button in "Table output" properties ends with following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:113)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.open(DatabaseDialog.java:61)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.step.BaseStepDialog.showDbDialogUnlessCancelledOrValid(BaseStepDialog.java:808)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.step.BaseStepDialog$AddConnectionListener.widgetSelected(BaseStepDialog.java:1487)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutputDialog.open(TableOutputDialog.java:888)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonStepsDelegate.editStep(SpoonStepsDelegate.java:120)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.editStep(Spoon.java:8814)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.editStep(TransGraph.java:3287)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.mouseDoubleClick(TransGraph.java:785)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1384)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7949)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9331)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:710)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
```

My Java version is 1.8.0_231, so Java version should be fine (I know Pentaho 8.3 requires Java 8)

Comment: Can you double check that you have both java_home and kettle_home environment variables set? In my experience, this error is occasionally related to missing environment variables.

Comment: I already fixed the by problem by setting up Ubuntu VM and run Spoon there. But thanks for the help